# Best Windows application for mounting Amazon S3 as a Windows drive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can anyone recommend an application, preferably free and open source, that allows one to mount Amazon S3 storage as a Windows drive?  We use Windows 7 64 bit.

I'm trying out ExpandDrive now but it's pretty buggy.  I was unable to transfer a 1GB file after 4 attempts.

Thank you,
Fred.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://rclone.org/ with winfsp and NSSM to install the mount as windows service . I strongly not advise to do it since it consumes a lot of requests on each access.

Answer (score 0):

Fred,

I'm using CloudBerry Drive. It's not free, but the cost is quite reasonable: $40 one time. Unfortunately it's not open source.

Thanks,
Peter G